# Use POST to send data to multiple aspx files

Tags: c#, asp.net

While practicing `C#` with `ASP.NET` I'm making writing board.

In `View.aspx` file, I made two buttons, each connects to `Modify.aspx`, and `Delete.aspx`. Since both actions require password check, (to verify the writers)
I made text input box for users to insert their password before clicking modify, or delete.

However, the problem is, how can I send post to two different page. From `View.aspx` to `Modify.aspx` and `Delete.aspx`? Since `POST` method requires `action =` form which designates object which gets the data, I'm not sure how can I send data from `View.aspx` to two different pages. Though I thought about using `GET`, `POST` together, since content is password, `GET` is not proper.

Below is part of my code. (`View.aspx`)

```
<%@ Page Language = "C#" AutoEventWireup = "true" CodeFile = "View.aspx.cs" Inherits = "Article_view" %>
    <TABLE class=bg_wh cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=799 border=0>
                <TBODY>
                    <TR vAlign=top>
                        <TD height=20></TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR vAlign=top>
                        <TD align=middle>

                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="749">                                              
                                <tr><td height="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"></td></tr>

                                <tr bgcolor="#F2F2F2">
                                    <td height="30" class="left pdnt_3"><b>&nbsp;Writer : <%= writer %> </b></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td height="1" bgcolor="#DFDFDF"></td></tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td height="27" class="right gul f11 pdnt_3">Title :  <%= title%> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td height="1" bgcolor="#DFDFDF"></td></tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td height="27" class="right gul f11 pdnt_3">Content :  <%= content%> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td height="1" bgcolor="#DFDFDF"></td></tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td height="27" class="right gul f11 pdnt_3">Date :  <%= writedate %> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td height="1" bgcolor="#DFDFDF"></td></tr>

                            </table>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="749">
                            <tr style="padding-top:10;">
                                <td align="right">
                                <input type = "text" id = "passwordInsertion" name = write_password />
                                <input type="button" class="modify_button" value="modify" onclick = "window.open('Write.aspx','Write');"/>
                                <input type="button" class="delete_button" value="delete" onclick = "window.open('Write.aspx','Write');"/>
                                <input type="button" class="list_button" value="list" onclick = "window.open('List.aspx','_self');"/>
                            </tr>
                        </table>    


                        <br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

So I edited again, but it does not properly send a data

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function UpdateToModifyForm() {
        form_obj = document.getElementById("View_form");
        document.View_form.action = "Modify.aspx";
        form_obj.submit();
    }

    function UpdateToDeleteForm() {
        form_obj = document.getElementById("View_form");
        document.View_form.action = "Delete.aspx";
        form_obj.submit();
    }

</script>

......................

<form id = "View_form" method = "post">



<input type = "text" id = "passwordInsertion" name = write_password />
                                <input type="button" class="modify_button" value="modify" onclick = "UpdateToModifyForm();"/>
                                <input type="button" class="delete_button" value="delete" onclick = "UpdateToDeleteForm();"/>
```

And my `Delete.aspx.cs` file is like below. (just to check whether password is well send through `POST`)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Article_Delete : CWebBase
{
    public string password;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        password = Request.Form["write_password"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript you can do as follows

give your form a name attribute say "nameOfTheForm"

```
function UpdateToModifyForm() {
    document.nameOfTheForm.action = "modify.aspx";
}

function UpdateToDeleteForm() {
    document.nameOfTheForm.action = "delete.aspx";
}
```

Then on your button clicks you can add these functions to the proper buttons.

Comment: Can I do same thing with javascript only without jquery. I personally want to try with really basic codes.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but using javascript did not work. I think I have to find some problem while using form attribute.